# How to link to Teams document and have it open in Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it possible to create a link to a document in Teams and have it actually open in Teams (assuming it's installed), rather than in a web browser?

Answer (score 0):

The browser may be configured as the default app used to open your links.

You can change the default app in your client this way:

[image]

Comment: Hmm... not sure if this is what I'm looking for or not. There is an excel file I share with others in Teams. Ultimately what I want to do is put a shortcut on my desktop that will open it up. I only know how to create a web link though... so I don't think this solution would apply to that since the "link" is a URL. But what you're showing here might indicate that I could save it in a different way? Hope that makes sense.